# MVC 3 dropdown list not getting any values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, c#-4.0, razor

I have a dropdownlist in an MVC 3 create page, however I am not getting any values when I POST the page.  My code is as follows :-

View :-

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "League", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    
        League

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.League.fk_CountryID, "Country")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("fk_CountryID", "--Select One--")                                               *              
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.League.fk_CountryID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.League.LeagueName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.League.LeagueName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.League.LeagueName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.League.Image)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        Upload File: <input type="file" name="Image" />
    </div>


    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

Controller :-

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "Image")]Country country, HttpPostedFileBase Image, League league)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            model.League = league;

            try
            {
                foreach (string file in Request.Files)
                {
                    HttpPostedFileBase fileUploaded = Request.Files[file];

                    if (fileUploaded.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] imageSize = new byte[fileUploaded.ContentLength];
                        fileUploaded.InputStream.Read(imageSize, 0, (int)fileUploaded.ContentLength);
                        model.League.Image = imageSize;
                    }
                }

                db.Leagues.AddObject(model.League);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("uploadError", e);
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?  Cannot get the dropdownlist value in the controller.

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: How does your models look like? Why does your POST controller action takes so many arguments? Why aren't you using view models? To which collection property on your model is your dropdownlist bound to?

Comment: my model is an EF model.  Country has CountryID, CountryName and Image.  League has LeagueID, fk_CountryID, LeagueName and Image.  My controller is getting the Image, Country and League.  I am using ViewModels, model.League = league; . My dropdownlist is bound to the Country model.

Comment: I think you might have some misunderstanding about what a view model is. View models should not contain or reference any domain specific objects. Your `Country` and `League` classes are domain models. They have nothing to do in a view. View models are classes that are specifically designed for your views.

Comment: in my ViewModel I have the following :-         public League League { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<League> Leagues { get; set; }

Comment: Ok fixed it, added a SelectList in my ViewModel!

Answer (score 1):

Ok fixed it by adding a SelectList in my ViewModel as follows :-

```
        //Countries dropdown List
    public SelectList CountryList { get; set; }
    public string SelectedCountry { get; set; }

        public LeagueData PopulateCountriesDDL(string selected, Country country)
    {
        var typeList = new SelectList(db.Countries.ToList(), "CountryID", "CountryName", selected);
        LeagueData model = new LeagueData { CountryList = typeList, Country = country, SelectedCountry = selected };

        return model;
    }
```

Comment: See my DDL tutorials http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx